# Why when i add an item in bag collection nhibernate automatically insert in database?

Tags: c#, asp.net, nhibernate

I'm working with NHibernate. My A class have a bag of B objects. so when i try:

```
var A = new A();
var B = new B();

A.Bs.Add(B);  // Here NHibernate insert in database
```

The Nhibernate automatically insert in relationship table on database. But i want to NHibernate insert when i save or update the A object:

```
var A = new A();
var B = new B();

A.Bs.Add(B);
session.saveOrUpdate(A);  // Here i want to NHibernate insert in database
```

It's possible or this is how NHibernate works?
Thanks.

Comment: It's how NH works by default with Session FlushMode = Auto.

Comment: The code you've shown in block 1 does not seem right. Constructing a new A should have nothing to do with the session. If NHibernate is inserting a record where you claim, then you must already have told NHibernate to save the 'A', before you added the B.

Answer (score 0):

You may need to use transactions

```
using (ITransaction transaction = session.BeginTransaction())
{
  var A = new A();
  var B = new B();
  A.Bs.Add(B);
  session.saveOrUpdate(A);
  transaction.commit();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

So, when you use call `A.Bs.Add(B);` NHibernate insert it, because probably A is a peristent object (you've loaded it from database), and it has updated all dependencies. You can use session.Evict() to detach object from session, and than use `session.saveOrUpdate(A);` to attach. In this case insert will be here: `session.saveOrUpdate(A);`

Answer (score 0):

In fact you probably **DO** use transactions. Because by default NHibernate won't do insert on  just adding entity to another collection. I've checked this behavior on my test model:

```
Blog blog = new Blog();
blog.Name = "test";
blog.CreatedAt = DateTime.Now;
session.SaveOrUpdate(blog);

var item = new Post(blog);
blog.Posts.Add(item); // item.Id still 0 here. That mean that no insert was made
```

So check your transaction scope. And another thing that could affect is session's flush mode. But even with such code

```
Blog blog = new Blog();
session.FlushMode = FlushMode.Always;
session.SaveOrUpdate(blog);

var item = new Post(blog);
blog.Posts.Add(item);
var blogs = session.QueryOver<Blog>().List();
```

Id is still 0. So look for transactions or session.Flush calls